# use angular 4 Pipe in 2 component

Tags: angular, angular-datatables, angular2-custom-pipes

I have component base angular4 app and in every component i'm using **DataTable** Plugin and custom **DataFilterPipe**, when i import like below in every component the error i get is **ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type DataFilterPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules. Please consider moving DataFilterPipe to a higher module**. then i created a new module called **dataFilterModule**

import:

```
import {DataTableModule} from "angular2-datatable";
import {DataFilterPipe} from "../plugins/datatable/datafilterpipe";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
```

dataFilterModule:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {DataTableModule} from "angular2-datatable";
import {DataFilterPipe} from "../plugins/datatable/datafilterpipe";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DataTableModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DataFilterPipe
    ],
    exports: [
        DataFilterPipe
    ]
})
export class dataFilterModule {}
```

then import this module in my **AppModule** but!! the error i get is:

```
The pipe 'dataFilter' could not be found
```

I added exported dataFilterModule like below but there is no any good news!

```
export class dataFilterModule {
   static forRoot() {
     return {
         ngModule: DataFilterPipe,
         providers: [],
     };
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
My custom filter:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dataFilter'
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[], query: string): any {
        if (query) {
        return _.filter(array, row=>row.name.indexOf(query) > -1);
     }
    return array;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is a Shared Module. Check out [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254469/angular4-how-to-declare-components-import-modules-for-lazy-loaded-submodules/45255000#45255000) I answered a few days ago.

Comment: after creating the SharedModule i should import it in AppModule or any component i need?

Comment: Yep, the key is to make sure you export the components, directives...PIPES you might need in other modules. Once you import the shared module into the module you need it in, you can then import the individual components, directives, etc. Into specific parts of the module.

Comment: Thank you, but the **The pipe 'dataFilter' could not be found** error still exists.

Comment: please take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/MortezaAghili/4e30566fe3753ca0e5fea5d5818727c1

Comment: This may sound crazy but have you tried killing the server and rebuilding the app?

Comment: after you said yes, but nothing happed. the error still exists. do you looked at my gist? is it correct?

Comment: You are also exporting a few things you should'nt be. You shouldn't be exporting CommonModule. You want to be careful that you don't duplicate exports/imports....the way I see it is if I am exporting something using a Shared Module, that should "in theory" be the only source the "thing" you are exporting/importing.

Comment: Finnaly, i should import ShareModule in every component i need no in my AppModule. thanks

Answer (score 1):

After checking [@joshrathke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625304/joshrathke)
 joshrathke answer i found the solution. You should create **ShareModule** then import your Directive, component or pipes and for using this. you should import **ShareModule** in every component you need!

Comment: Share root with "forRoot" and import the share module aim your app module.